create_image parameter image error: _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist
Hello I am trying to display a chess board and when I get to the create_image part I am getting the following issue:
Exception has occurred: TclError image "pyimage1" doesn't exist    File "D:\Documents\DynamicDifficultyAdjustment\dda copy\dynamic_difficulty_adjustment_chess.py", line 50, in draw_pieces
    self.canvas.create_image(coords, image=piece_image, anchor="c", tags="piece")   File "D:\Documents\DynamicDifficultyAdjustment\dda copy\dynamic_difficulty_adjustment_chess.py", line 31, in __init__
    self.draw_pieces()   File "D:\Documents\DynamicDifficultyAdjustment\dda copy\dynamic_difficulty_adjustment_chess.py", line 89, in <module>
    chess_ui = ChessUI()
               ^^^^^^^^^
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage1" doesn't exist

However I do not have an image called "pyimage1". I am using a debugger and I am getting the correct image_filename -> './Images/white_rook.png'. I am getting an image object as self.get_piece_image(piece) sets the piece_image variable to a Tk image object with correct coordinates and RGB. Moreover shouldn't the parameter image be initialized to a Tk image object just as the piece_image?
import chess
import chess.engine
import chess.svg
import random
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import os

# Create a Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Chess Game")
# !!! these 2 lines turned out to be causing the exception

board = chess.Board()

class ChessUI(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("Chess UI")
        self.geometry("400x400")

        self.board = chess.Board()

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=400, height=400)
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.draw_board()
        self.draw_pieces()

    def draw_board(self):
        for row in range(8):
            for col in range(8):
                color = "white" if (row + col) % 2 == 0 else "gray"
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(col * 50, row * 50, (col + 1) * 50, (row + 1) * 50, fill=color)

    def draw_pieces(self):
        # Clear the pieces first to avoid duplications
        self.clear_pieces()

        # Redraw the pieces
        for square in chess.SQUARES:
            piece = self.board.piece_at(square)
            if piece is not None:
                piece_image = self.get_piece_image(piece)
                coords = self.square_to_coords(square)
                if piece_image is not None:
                    self.canvas.create_image(coords, image=piece_image, anchor="c", tags="piece")
                else:
                    print(f"Failed to load image for piece at square {square}.")
                
    def clear_pieces(self):
        # Clear only the pieces by deleting items with the "piece" tag
        self.canvas.delete("piece")

    def get_piece_image(self, piece):        
        # Directory containing the images
        image_dir = "./Images/"

        # Dictionary mapping piece symbols to image file names
        piece_images = {
            'r': os.path.join(image_dir, 'black_rook.png'),
            'n': os.path.join(image_dir, 'black_knight.png'),
            'b': os.path.join(image_dir, 'black_bishop.png'),
            'q': os.path.join(image_dir, 'black_queen.png'),
            'k': os.path.join(image_dir, 'black_king.png'),
            'p': os.path.join(image_dir, 'black_pawn.png'),
            'R': os.path.join(image_dir, 'white_rook.png'),
            'N': os.path.join(image_dir, 'white_knight.png'),
            'B': os.path.join(image_dir, 'white_bishop.png'),
            'Q': os.path.join(image_dir, 'white_queen.png'),
            'K': os.path.join(image_dir, 'white_king.png'),
            'P': os.path.join(image_dir, 'white_pawn.png')
        }
        piece_symbol = piece.symbol()
        
        image_filename = piece_images.get(piece_symbol, None)
        return ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(image_filename))

    def square_to_coords(self, square):
        file, rank = chess.square_file(square), chess.square_rank(square)
        x = (file * 50) + 25
        y = (7 - rank) * 50 + 25
        return x, y
    
chess_ui = ChessUI()
chess_ui.mainloop()


Does this answer your question? Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?

@Христо Иванов. Where can I download images  png?

It is better to provide a [mre] as currently class chess.Board is not defined. @Thingamabobs It is not a duplicate of the linked question as the issue of the linked question is the image not being shown, but not raise the mentioned exception.

Hello, I have added a minimal reproducable example. Turnes out the lines I ommited since I thought were irrelevant namely: root = tk.Tk() were causing this issue.
Maybe it is because that is a second instance of tk? The lines were from a previous attempt to show the board. Anyway I left a comment where they are and would still appreciate someone explaining why this was the case.

btw @toyotaSupra , you can download any images put them in a folder and name them with the names of the chess pieces and you would reproduce it.
